# Maven dependency on original Spring Boot JAR

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I'm using Spring Boot with the spring boot maven plugin which creates a JAR with

The JAR created by the plugin puts the classes in subdirectory in the JAR which means that I can't use the JAR as a dependency in maven.

Is there a way to declare a depenency in maven on the original JAR. I see that there is a `*.jar.original` file in the `target` directory so maybe I can create a dependency on that in the way it's possible to create a dependency on the test classes by declaring a dependency of the kind `test-jar`.

Just for clarification: I'm doing this testing/easier debugging, not for production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the other way around bout you can put a classifier to the Spring-Boot Jar in the repackage goal and let maven build your normal jar during the packaging phase:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html#classifier

Comment: That's not at all helpful. When using the classifier, the original jar gets replaced, unless you use attach=true, in which the original jar still gets renamed to .jar.original, and a normal dependency will still point to the non-original jar.